DropShadow Maui, effects from WPF
I am wondering is it possible in MAUI get a DropShadowEffect and GradientOrigin, RadiusX, RadiusY in RadialGradientBrush?
These are from WPF:
<Grid.Effect>
  <DropShadowEffect Direction="270" Opacity=".7" BlurRadius="4" Color="Red"/>
</Grid.Effect>

<RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.5,0.3" Center="0.5,0.5" RadiusX="1.8" RadiusY="1.3" />

Can we get something similar in MAUI? Some properties like GradientOrigin and RadiusX, RadiusY are missing in MAUI.

you could try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/border?view=net-maui-8.0 with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/brushes/gradient?view=net-maui-8.0

Maui has the similar element. You can check the shadow, The VisualElement class has a Shadow bindable property, of type Shadow, that enables a shadow to be added to any layout or view.
  <Grid>
      <Grid.Shadow>
          <Shadow Brush="Black"
              Offset="20,20"
              Radius="40"
              Opacity="0.8" />
      </Grid.Shadow>
  </Grid>

